# what's SCORM and how to use it in Tin Can API?

Tags: scorm, tin-can-api

I am new to the SCORM and Tin Can API. Can anyone explain me what's SCORM. how to generate statement with the SCORM cloud credentials.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question is a bit vague. There are plenty of docs on the web that cover the basics of SCORM and Tin Can (now called the Experience API or xAPI). You could start here: http://tincanapi.com/overview/

If you are trying to figure out how to save Tin Can statements to the SCORM Cloud, I suggest you take a look at the ADL's xAPI wrapper: https://github.com/adlnet/xAPIWrapper.

You should be able to get up and running quickly by changing the following credentials in the [example.html](https://github.com/adlnet/xAPIWrapper/blob/master/example.html) page.

```
ADL.XAPIWrapper.changeConfig({
  'endpoint': 'https://cloud.scorm.com/tc/YOUR_LRS_ENDPOINT_HERE/',
  'user': 'YOUR_USERNAME_HERE',
  'password': 'YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE'
});
```

Comment: Also note an alternative JavaScript library and libraries for other languages can be found at http://tincanapi.com/libraries

Comment: Example.html link moved: https://github.com/adlnet/xAPIWrapper/blob/master/examples/example.html

Answer (score 1):

SCORM is a JavaScript based standard that allows courses to communicate to an LMS. TinCan is a  model that allows web content to communicate data, via REST, to a Learning Resource Store. They are different entirely. If you are generating statements then you are talking purely about Tin Can API (aka: eXperience API or xAPI).

To create a statement that will post data to the cloud.scorm.com LRS you will need to make sure you have followed all the steps at "How to get started with SCORM Cloud API" http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud-developers/how-to-get-started-with-the-scorm-cloud-api/

To initialize your account and begin to send statements take a look at this page http://cloud.scorm.com/doc/web-services/api.html specifically the following code and replace [your app id], and [your secret key] with your specific credentials when you build out your app.

ScormCloud.Configuration = new RusticiSoftware.HostedEngine.Client.Configuration([your services url], [your app id], [your secret key]);

Answer (score 0):

SCORM and Tin Can API (now Experience API or xAPI) are both separate eLearning standards. Tin Can API is a newer/latest version of SCORM and has got a different name because it is quite different from SCORM.

If you want to generate statements you will first need a content, you can find several sample content online, or if you need to custom generate content you will need a Javascript library (there are free libraries available). SCORM Cloud credentials or any other LRS authentication credentials can be used with these content/library to send statement to the LRS/Scorm Cloud.